# How does the Spotify API match non-English data (e.g. artist name)?

Tags: json, translation, spotify

I am running queries against the Spotify API requesting track and artist names. In one case I requested "Gentle Wave" by "Soul Media" and the returned json had non-English characters:

artist name:
"name" : "稲垣次郎とソウル・メディア"

track name:
"name" : "ジェントル・ウェイヴ"

My script tries to match the English strings to the artist and track names in the json, but obviously fails.

Is there some way to pull the English strings from the API so that I can match them? There is obviously some linkage between the English and non-English strings, but I don't know how to access it.